# How to view the PDF files in tally using tdl?

Tags: tally

I am using tally and i want to view the PDF file in tally using tdl program.
so plz help me out to get best result.

```
Example:
```

For viewing Image using tdl program in tally

[Part : image]

```
GRAPH TYPE : "image path here"   // To display image in tally

width      :  30
height     :  30
```

as shown as above code , i need to display PDF file in tally.
so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Its Not possible to view the PDF File with in the Tally Application. But you can use Browse URL action and can provide the path of the PDF file and you can open by using third party application